# Create custom dropdown for custom module in magento product edit section

Tags: magento2, product, php, custom

I have created my own custom module for "Critic Expert" feature. I want to assign a critic expert with each product so I have to add my custom dropdown with each product.

How would I can show the dropdown with my custom module values and save it along with product in admin section.

Please find attached screenshot for more details.

[image]

Comment: @Neeraj Sharma, I have create small module for this you can download from below link. [download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YTVCOfxmqGGq10rKv3WuGBT56iFAdVrf/view?usp=sharing). You just need to share your selected option data to product data-provider.

Comment: I had same requirement and created one module for it. Is it fine to create Critics List attribute and assign it with product by pragmatically ?

Answer (score 2):

I have created Small module. It will help you.

Create module files which are listed below.

**app/code/Kunj/Critic/etc/module.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Kunj_Critic" setup_version="2.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Kunj/Critic/Model/Critic/Options.php**

```
<?php

namespace Kunj\Critic\Model\Critic;


class Options implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            [
                'value'=>1,
                'label'=>"My Option"
            ],
            [
                'value'=>2,
                'label'=>"My Option 2"
            ],
            [
                'value'=>3,
                'label'=>"My Option 3"
            ],
            [
                'value'=>4,
                'label'=>"My Option 4"
            ],
            [
                'value'=>5,
                'label'=>"My Option 5"
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**app/code/Kunj/Critic/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="product-details">
        <field name="critic_lists" sortOrder="300" formElement="select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Kunj\Critic\Model\Critic\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Critic Lists</label>
                <dataScope>critic_lists</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**app/code/Kunj/Critic/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Kunj_Critic',
    __DIR__
);
```

After create module run :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: How I save these option in database

Comment: this code for save those data in you custom table.